# Code in button click c# happens after the function finishes

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have some simple C# code that is triggered on a Button Press. The button press first clears some ListBoxes, then changes the text of a label, and then calls a function.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
    listBox2.Items.Clear();
    listBox3.Items.Clear();
    listBox4.Items.Clear();
    label5.Text = "Getting links...";
    process(url);
    label5.Text = "Finished";
}
```

But the Lists are cleared and the label is changed after `process()` is finished executing. This ruins the purpose as I'm changing the label so that the user is aware that some action is taking place. How can I make the initial label change before the function `process()` finishes?

Comment: Try to insert `label5.Refresh()` after the `label5.Text = "Getting links...";`

Comment: Try to read about the `async` keyword.

Comment: label5.Refresh() works, thanks TaW

Comment: @Stefan `async` will do nothing here. It *doesn't* make anything run asynchronously, it's syntactic sugar to make awaiting for already asynchronous operations easier.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: the async keyword is valid here, although the `process` method should be made async or launched from a task. I was pointing to it because the patterns beats the `Refresh` and `DoEvents` anwsers in responsiveness of the application. The onclick scenario is even mentioned in the msdn reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156513.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `process` method is long-running, it can cause UI freezing and prevent UI from redrawing - that's why you don't see your label text immediate update.

Simpliest way to achieve your goal - is call `label5.Refresh()` right after `label5.Text = "Getting links...";`, this will immediately cause invalidation and redrawing of label.

Or even you can call `this.Refresh()` if more than one control should be updated - this will update whole usercontrol or form owns your controls.

But note - if your `process` method runs a **very** long time (more than a 2-3 seconds for example) - you should consider doing it asyncroniously in thread separate from UI. It is considered as "good style" because it will not cause UI freezing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `async` keyword. Only when accessing the UI from different thread you have to use the `Invoke`

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(
        () =>
            {
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                    {
                        listBox1.Items.Clear();
                        listBox2.Items.Clear();
                        listBox3.Items.Clear();
                        listBox4.Items.Clear();
                        myLabel.Text = "Getting links...";
                    });
            });

    this.process(url);

    await Task.Run(
        () =>
            {
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { myLabel.Text = "Finished"; });
            });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using a `Task` to run `process(url)` in a "thread" separated from GUI?
In this way GUI will stay responsive to the user ang got "refreshed", then, when your task ends, you just have to update GUI label.

When you have ops that must take a bit of time, you should always separate them from GUI. My two cents.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options. either use a different thread to run `process(url)`, or add before it `Application.DoEvents()`.